# Why shouldn't I use delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like for someone to explain why I shouldn't use delay in the below code. I've been told by a different developer I should use `setTimeout` in the first animate as a callback.

But I don't understand why?

Would it be possible to show me how to use `setTimeout` in the code I have below if it is infact the best way to go about it..

```
function fadingSlider() {
    $(items[index]).animate({ "right": "0" }, 500).delay(5000).animate({ "right": "-1000px" }, 500, fadingSlider );
    index++;
    if (index === items.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the other developer didn't explain _why_ `delay()` was bad I would ignore the advice.

Comment: `.delay()` is fine to use between jQuery methods. I don't see anything wrong with this.

Comment: `delay()` works on queue and as you are using animate() methods which use fx queue, this is all fine here... I guess maybe this is because you cannot clear a delay unlike a timeout. AFAIK, on some older jQuery version, it was possible to cancel delay() usinfg `finish()` but seems like inconsitent across jQuery version, if i'm still correct. And the jQuery DOC mentions nothing about it

Comment: If there's no need to cancel the delay at any point, there is really never a reason to use a timeout. Any function can be added to the standard effects queue with the `.queue()` method. Quite unknown and very underappreciated. Also missing in the main answer that was linked to by the way.